# How do I go about running k-means on my grayscale video sequence?

Tags: matlab, statistics, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation

I have a sequence of 2D grayscale images for which I would like to run the k-means clustering algorithm on. My data is in the form m x n x p where p is the number of frames.

The matlab code available in the statistics toolbox expects the data X to be in the form 
n-by-p data matrix where the "Rows of X correspond to points, columns correspond to variables."

Can I use this code? How do I adapt my data to be in the expected format?

Thanks in Advance,

n

p.s. Also, if possible I'd prefer not to use a function from the statistics toolbox, if somebody can recommend something else (such as a mex function). It would be much appreciated.

Comment: what do you consider a "point" in your settings? a pixel? a 2D patch? a spatio-temporal patch?

Comment: In general, a point in my data would correspond to a voxel.

Comment: Interested to know why the question has been down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26532-image-segmentation-using-otsu-thresholding) function.

It the otsu algorithm base on multi-class segementation.

For multiclass, you can use `im2bw`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question, what's the difference between Otsu's algorithm and k-means?

Comment: They are just 2 different segementation algorithm. K-mean search for neighboor and Ostu search the best way to threshold the image. [otsu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method) and [k-mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)